# Calcular edad en base a una fecha con un formato específico

Tags: date, unix, formato

mi primera pregunta por aqui:

Quiero calcular la edad de mis usuarios y tengo la fecha en el siguiente formato, por ejemplo: June 16, 2005

Estoy usando osclass y para capturar la fecha de nacimiento le pido con un datapicker jquery al cliente y lo almacena en base de datos como formato segundos unix.

Se me ocurrio pasar esta fecha "June 16, 2005" a unix y luego trabajarla usando la fecha de hoy, ¿Como puedo hacerlo? ¿A alguien se le ocurre algo?

Gracias!!!

Comment: Ya lo resolví, lo dejo por aquí por si a alguien le interesa.

`código` <li> EDAD: <?php $tiempo = $custom_field_value['nacimiento']; echo floor((time() - strtotime($tiempo)) / 31556926);?> AÑOS  </li>

Comment: Si ya solucionaste tu pregunta seria bueno que compartieras  tu solucion,  publica una respuesta como si fueras otro usuario.

Comment: No es necesario crear otro usuario para auto-responderte. Abajo del todo de la página hay un *checkbox* para, precisamente, **responder tu propia pregunta**. Es perfectamente válido hacerlo, y futuros usuarios te lo agradecerán.